# Recursive without global variable, loops only ones for one arg

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need help for this task. I have tried several ways np . I used "typeof fun.tab === 'undefined'". Any idea?

Modify the definition of the recursive following so that in the calculation of the fun (n) for any k <= n value fun (k) was calculated exactly once. Of course, the function 
is to remain a purely recursive (not use  loops).

We must not introduced into the environment "external / global" , no new variables.

```
var fun = function (arg) {


    /*some code*/


    if(arg<=1){
      return 1;
    else {
      return fun(n-1) + fun(n-2);
    }

    /*some code*/



}
```

I try this ...

```
var fun = function (arg) {

    console.log(arg);
    var n = arg;
    if (typeof tab === 'undefined') {
        var tab = [];
    } 

        if(this in tab) {
            return 1;
        } else {

            tab[this] = this;


            if(arg<=1){
                return 1;
            } else {

                return fun(n-1) + fun(n-2);
            }
        }

}

fun(10);
```

Its not work ;/

Comment: Can you do anything else besides copy/paste?

Comment: No  its task of my last exam. I am Java programer ;/

Comment: Dude, this has nothing to do with not knowing javascript. It has to do with being a programmer. Study more about the concept of recursion. Google it. You can get the answer. Be a good programmer, not one that always has to have the dude at the next desk give him the answer.

Comment: There is a missing closing bracket. And `n` and `f` are never defined. Do you mean `arg` and `fun`?

Comment: I need to pass the exam . Its terrible. I have tried many ways.

Comment: yeah f its fun and n=arg

Comment: k its any natural number

Comment: "*I need to pass the exam*" - that's not how SO works. And you're supposed to find the solution yourself. Hints: Use more parameters, or a local function with a different return type.

Comment: I do not want a solution only hint. Thx Bergi

Comment: Just cache the result of `fun(n)` calls in an object map which you are passing along to `fun`. The signature could look like `fun(n, cache)`. Then within every invocation of `fun(n)`, check wheter `typeof cache[n - 1] === 'undefined'` or `typeof cache[n - 2] === 'undefined'` prior to invoking `fun` again for those. If there's nothing in the cache, compute the value and store it in the cache, otherwise just use the cached value. @Bergi Is this what you were thinking as well?

Comment: THX  plalx  ;-) So much ...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , finally i do this ;-) ITS  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 , thanks for plalx . You are great Human ;p

```
var fun = function (arg) {
        var n = arg;
        console.log(n);

        if(typeof this.cache === 'undefined') {
            this.cache = [];
        }


        if (typeof this.cache[n - 1] === 'undefined' && typeof  this.cache[n - 2] === 'undefined') {
                this.cache[n - 1] = arg;
                this.cache[n - 2] = arg;

                if(arg<=1){
                    return 1;
                } else {

                    return fun(n-1) + fun(n-2);
                }
            } else {

                return 1;
            }


    }
```

Comment: Hm, I did purposely not mention [memoisation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=memoize+fibonacci+%5Bjavascript%5D), as I did consider this to be not pure (functional). Introducing the `cache` is creating an external/global value, even if it's not a variable but a property.

Comment: @Bergi Well, if you pass a cache object around and rather than mutating it you simply create a new one every time, then everything is immutable and it still works as expected. What other ideas did you have in mind?

Comment: @user3604928 I'm glad I could help. It's not exactly this I had in mind and I do not think your function will yield the correct result, since you are caching `arg`, rather than the computation of `fun(n - x)` and rather than returning the cached value, you also simply return `1`, but I guess you are on the right track.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, passing an immutable list of already computed values around was what I thought of. However, I wouldn't call that a "cache" any more - and the `.cache` in this answer is a static, global, mutable object